# link menu items to the same page, but showing different div

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

i'm trying to link three menu items to the same page, showing different div based on what i clicked.

In this page i have a dropdown menu, every option of the menu shows a specific div and hide the others. Once the menu-item is clicked, what should happen is:

1. open the page
2. shows the correct dropdown menu option
3. shows the div related to the selected option.

Here, the code of the dropdown menu enterd in the linked page.

HTML

```
<select id="test" name="form_select" onchange="showDiv(this)">
<option value="hidden_div1">Show div 1</option>
<option value="hidden_div2">Show div 2</option>
<option value="hidden_div3">Show div 3</option>
<option value="hidden_div4">Show div 4</option>
</select>

<div id="hidden_div1">This is hidden div 1</div>
<div id="hidden_div2">This is hidden div 2</div>
<div id="hidden_div3">This is hidden div 3</div>
<div id="hidden_div4">This is hidden div 4</div>
```

CSS

```
div[id*="hidden_div"] {
  display: none;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// When the page loads, make sure the already selected div is shown.
window.onload = function afterPageIsLoaded() {
    showDiv();
}

function showDiv(element) {
    // Create an array of all the hidden divs elements.
    const hiddenDivs = [...document.querySelectorAll("div[id*='hidden_div']")];

    // Loop over them and hide every one of them.
    hiddenDivs.map(hiddenDiv => hiddenDiv.style.display = 'none');

    // Get the selected id from the select.
    const id = document.getElementById('test').value;

    // Get the selected div and display it.
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

( And this the related fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/5pemtkh8/4/) )

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is wrong with the js-fiddle? seems to be working properly for me

Comment: Sorry, i maybe have to be more clear. The fiddel works well (i post it only to show how the dropdown menu works in the page). My problem is to link, **from the menu of the site**, to the page with a specific option of the dropdown menu selcted. 
For example:
1. when i click the button "A" on the site menu, i load the page with the dropdown that displays the option "hidden_div1" and the related div "hidden_div1".
2. When i click the button "B" on the site menu, i load the page with the dropdown that displays the option "hidden div2" and the related div "hidden_div2".

Comment: Maybe i am just stupid, but to clearify, you want the dropdown items to work similar to an <a> attribute? Again, you want to use the menu items as a clickable link to another website?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't know the English well. Thanks, again. I try to resume: in the site are two menus. The first one is the classical, general menu of the site. The second one, is a dropdown menu placed in a single page (this second dropdown menu works well, and let me to show different div in the same page. The code posted in the ticket refers to this second menu). So...i have to link the general menu to the specific option of the dropdown menu.